# Keyboard Typing Problem

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard will extra type two keys wehwen I pressed e, d, c, or 3. Resulting in the following giberrish:

```
we ds xc 23
```

The information I got was this is the keyboard problem. Changing the keyboard [will solve this problem](http://dsandler.org/wp/archives/2006/09/10/a-fix-for-conjoined-dell-laptop-keys). Since I am using desktop, the solution in the article ( reseating keyboard connector) is not practical.

Any idea how to fix it without changing the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like something (e.g. coffee) was spilled over the keyboard. It happens all the time at work.

Solution:

1. Wash the keyboard, and hang it to dry. But be warned, it isn't 100% safe for electronics.
2. Buy new keyboard.

hope that helps

Comment: Buying new keyboard is the most cost effective way.

Answer (score 0):

Open it up and clean it. A typical [keyboard switch mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology) consists of various layers and when junk gets in there it causes all sorts of weird behavior.

Do *not* wash the whole keyboard with tap water. The chlorine and minerals will damage the circuits (it'll probably take a long time though). When people wash electronics, they use either **distilled** or **deionized** water.