# Keyboard Typing Problem

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard, display-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Typing Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/90306/keyboard-typing-problem)

When I got home from work yesterday I couldn't log in on my account on my desktop PC (Acer Aspire M5620). The reason for this was that when I was typing, more digits would appear than I pressed. After logging into an account that required no password (my Dad's) I found out that some of my key bindings were messed up.

For instance when typing:

```
W --- qwe would appear
q --- qw + right mouse
e --- we
a --- as
s --- asd
d --- sd
z --- zx
x --- zxc
c --- xc
```

Moreover pressing:

```
1 --- 12
2 --- 123
3 --- 23
```

I am typing this from my Dad's laptop (which is working like a charm). Is there a way to fix it? I'm not the brainy type when it comes to computers.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard with the same computer?

Comment: well now that it has come to mind, i found out i do not own a second keyboard... i will ask a friend of mine to bring his one over and i'll inform you when its done.

Comment: ok here is an update... instead of connecting a new keyboard to the pc (to find out if its the pc or the keyboards problem) i connected the keyboard to my dad's laptop. Result: the keyboard reacted the same way on my dad's laptop as on my pc... After disconecting the keyboard my dad's laptop was fine (nothing changed in his build-in-keyboard settings)...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a simple solution. I bought a new (and improved) keyboard. It works like a charm. Probably something wrong with the keyboard itself.

Ty Moshen, for putting me on this (actually very simple) idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the keyboard :P